# how to get link in dictionary?

Tags: python

```
@app.route('/<variable>')
def daily(variable):
    youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+variable 
    search = SearchVideos(variable,offset=1,mode="json",max_results=1)
    y = json.loads(search.result())
    print(y)
    
    return redirect(youtubeUrl)
```

and my output;
[image]

I try to get 'link' in this output but didnt work what i write so how can i?

Comment: add `y` as text to the question

Comment: `y['search_result'][0]['link']` gives you the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
youtube_url = y['search_result'][0]['link']
```

`y` is a dict. Inside the dict there is a list pointed by the key `search_result`. The first item in the list is a dict with a key named `link`